# When declaring a multi-dimensional array in C++, why do you only have to specify a size for the second dimensions?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

For example, why is arr[ ][5] okay but arr[5][ ] not okay? How does this idea extend to greater dimensions? For example, could you define a three-dimensional array as arr[ ][ ][5] legally?

I'm just learning about MDAs for the first time and I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this, so I'd love to hear an explanation/walk through. Thank you!

Comment: Use `std::vector`.  If you need multidimensional, put the `std::vector` as a member variable inside a wrapper class to convert the indexes to the flat vector.

Answer (score 0):

> why is arr[ ][5] okay but arr[5][ ] not okay?

Because if you have "any number of groups of 5 things", you can place them all consecutively in memory and know exactly where each one goes - the first group of 5 things goes somewhere, then the next group goes 5-things-worth-of-space after that, and so on. But if you have "5 groups of any number of things", then you don't know ahead of time where the second and subsequent groups need to go. Further, you don't have a guarantee of the groups being all the same size, which is how a rectangular array is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

> why is arr[ ][5] okay but arr[5][ ] not okay?

This has to do with pointer arithmetic.

When you write `arr[ ][5]` the compiler knows that `arr` is an array, with each item is array of 5 `int` for example. Therefore it can do something like `arr++` which basically means a pointer to the "next" array of 5 `int`. That's possible because the size of the secondary array is known.

When you write  `arr[5][ ]` the compile can never what size is that of the secondary array, and so it cannot do any pointer arithmetic like `arr++`

> How does this idea extend to greater dimensions? For example, could you define a three-dimensional array as arr[ ][ ][5] legally?

No, all sizes must be explicit except for the first dimension.